# How to detect if a specific class link was clicked inside a DIV and override the DIV's click action then?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have several DIV of the following kind on my page:

```
<div class='entry'>
    This is a statement 
    <a title="Search @travel" class="app-context-link" href="">@travel</a>
</div>
```

When a DIV of class .entry is clicked I trigger the following:

```
$(".entry").on('click', function(e) {
   console.log("DIV Clicked");
});
```

When a link of the class .app-context-link is clicked I trigger the following:

```
var context_links = document.getElementsByClassName('app-context-link');

for (var k=0;k<context_links.length;++k) {
    context_links[k].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        console.log("The context link inside DIV is clicked");
    });
}
```

The question:

Right now when I click on the app-context-link both actions seem to be triggered: for the DIV (because a .click event is detected) and for the link (because there's an event listener on a link of that class).

How do I make it that if the link is clicked the DIV on click jQuery is not triggered?

I tried several possibilities, nothing worked. Also I would prefer not to reorganize the code too much, but simply add some directive in the on click jQuery part so that it detects if a link was clicked and does not do what it would normally do if the DIV was clicked.

Thank you!

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, why are you not using it for your link event handlers too? just use $('.entry').on('click', '.app-context-link', function (e) { ... }); This will add a delegate handler to your `.entry`, which will handle clicks for all `.app-context-link` in the div, rather than adding 1 handler for each link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use stop propagation :

```
context_links[k].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); //Here
    console.log("The context link inside DIV is clicked");
});
```

This will stop the click event from bubbling, so when you click on the `a`, click events of its ancestor will not trigger.

Answer (score 3):

you can use like this

```
$(".entry").on('click', function(e) {
e.stopPropagation();
alert($(this).prop("tagName"));
});
$(".entry a").on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
 e.stopPropagation();
alert($(this).prop("tagName"));
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UY6Q7/17/)